# EL evaluation in tags

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

In the below code snippet, the intention is to take value for name from a variable, however no value gets output when it is tried with EL, while direct assignment works fine.

```
<%! String sName; %>
<%  sName="ABC"; %>
<H3> Hello <c:out value="${sName}"/> </H3>
<H3> Hello <c:out value="ABC"/> </H3>
```

What is missing or has gone wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use java expression for passing the value. <H3> Hello <c:out value="<%= sName %>" /> </H3>                                         This should fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `${sName}`, it doesn't mean that page looks for local variable with name `sName`. Local variables you have are immaterial.

You can set `sName` for later use with something like `request.setAttribute("sName", "some value")` from scriptlet. Or you can use jstl tag: `<c:set var="sName" value="some value"/>`.

There's also an option to use scriptlet to print value of your local variable, as you noted: `<%= sName %>`